Arriving at different solutions to the same differential equation problem
With different approaches, I am arriving at different solution to the same particular integral.
$$
    y_p = \frac{1}{D^2 + a^2} e^{i a x}
$$
First approach: Partial fraction approach
$$
    y_p = \frac{1}{D^2 + a^2} e^{i a x}
$$
$$
    y_p = \frac{1}{(D - ia)(D + ia)} e^{iax} 
$$
$$
    y_p = \left(\frac{1}{2ia}\right) \left( \frac{1}{D - ia} - \frac{1}{D + ia} \right) e^{iax}
$$
$$
    y_p = \left( \frac{1}{2ia} \right) \left( x e^{iax} - \frac{1}{2ia} \right) e^{iax}
$$
$$
    y_p = -\frac{ix}{2a} e^{iax} + \frac{1}{4a^2} e^{iax}
$$
Second approach: Using properties of ODE
$$
    y_p = \frac{1}{D^2 + a^2} e^{i a x}
$$
$$
    y_p = e^{iax} \frac{1}{(D + ia)^2 + a^2}
$$
$$
    y_p = e^{iax} \frac{1}{D(D + 2ia)} e^{0x}
$$
$$
    y_p = \frac{x}{2ia} e^{iax}
$$
$$
    y_p = -\frac{ix}{2a} e^{iax}
$$
In the above two approaches, the first term $-\frac{ix}{2a} e^{iax}$ is common. But, the second term $\frac{1}{4a^2} e^{iax}$ is not present when I solve the particular integral using the properties of ODE.
Is there an explanation as to why there is a difference the solutions?

$$\frac{1}{D^2+a^2}\neq \frac1{D-ia}--\frac1{D+ia}$$ You need to multiply the right side by $\frac1{2ia}.$

Without looking at the problem, there is a thing called a "solution space". In polynomial ODE theory at least, the degree of the operator corresponds to the dimension of the solution space, so just messing around you might find a couple without finding all of them. But you can usually know when you've got too many by the degree. As for rational operators (which I have not seen), there may be a similar result.

Since $(D^2+a^2)\frac{1}{4a^2}e^{iax}=0$, the difference is irrelevant.
